# Magento Product Page showing error page frontend and backend

Tags: magento-1.9

I was preparing to launch my site following this [checklist](http://tomrobertshaw.net/2010/09/37-point-magento-pre-launch-checklist/)

when I noticed that the product pages no longer loaded, showing the magento error page.

http://52.16.236.82/drilling/carbide-drills/general-machining.html

I have cleared the cache and reindexed but still the product pages wont load. The wierd thing is that the product details page wont load in the frontend or the backend.

All suggestions would help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide details in error log and other pages are loading properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. When uninstalling "unused" modules, a product attribute that had been added when I initially installed the module stopped the page loading.

I reinstalled the module and stopped the attribute been visible in the frontend.